# Rails: how to check if find_or_initialize is updating/creating/skipping?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have method which updating data in database from CSV.

```
csv_text = File.read("#{Rails.root}/db/seed/books.csv")
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => :first_row)
csv.each { |row|
row = row.to_hash.with_indifferent_access.to_hash.symbolize_keys
row.delete_if { |key, value| value.nil? }
book = Book.find_or_initialize_by_name(row[:name])
book.update_attributes!(row)
```

How can i check if record will be created or updated or nothing happens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To check if `book` was changed there's [`changed?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changed-3F):

```
book.changed?
```

To check if `book` is a new record there's [`new_record?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-new_record-3F):

```
book.new_record?
```

Comment: added
  puts "new record: #{rule_book.new_record?}"
  puts "changed: #{rule_book.changed?}"
between find and update new record work fine, but changed is always false

Comment: This is because `update_attributes` automatically saves the record. Assign the attributes with `book.attributes=row`, then check if `book.changed?` and call `save!` afterwards.